# How to list combination possibility in golang

Tags: go

Any idea to make the best code for combination :

with this :

```
letters := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
```

to have : `a ab ac ad abc abd b bc bcd` etc ...

regards and thanks

Comment: That pattern is not regular. Is this the complete output. 
`a ab ac ad abc abd b bc bcd, c, cd`

Comment: See Knuth, TAOCP §7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for Powerset:

One approach is:

Start with a `slice` with one empty element, let's call it result:

`[[]]`

Keep the previous slice, and create a new slice with first element `a` of you data structure added to you to every element in you original slice.

`[[]]` <--old; `[[a]]` <--new

merge them

`[[], [a]]`

Do the same thing for second element `b`:

`[[], [a]]` <--old; `[[b], [ab]]` <--new

=> `[[], [a], [b], [ab]]`

for `c`:

`[[], [a], [b], [ab]]` <--old; `[[c], [ac], [bc], [abc]]` <--new

=> `[[], [a], [b], [ab], [c], [ac], [bc], [abc]]`

and so on..

Comment: To complement that answer here is a great link that gives examples on how to manipulate slices https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks